# No outlet in bathroom?

Tags: electrical, bathroom, receptacle

My 1950's era house doesn't have any electrical receptacles in the bathroom. Doesn't the Building Code state there should be? I reside in California N.A.

Comment: What is your question? Whether 1950's electrical codes allowed a bathroom without an outlet? Likely the answer is "yes" since the house was apparently built without one. Unless significant remodeling is done, there's no need to bring an older home up to modern codes. (with some exceptions, like fire alarms and/or CO detectors being required)

Comment: If you had the home inspected prior to sale and the inspector's report did not note this, you should pry some money back from them for not inspecting/reporting well/throughly. As for the lack of outlet, at that era, nothing wrong with it, might even have been considered safer that way..

Comment: This is a convenience feature. Code permits it but does not require it. Check whether a  light fixture has an outlet; that was common during that period.

Answer (score 6):

Of course it is "allowed". Actually, what do you mean by allowed? Allowed by whom??

In newer homes newer codes apply, for the most part in an older home whatever was code at the time of installation is still code complaint today.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're wondering why you moved into a "new" home with no modern electrical is because for the most part only during a remodel and only when the walls are removed, is it required to wire/rewire.

Insurance companies may require the buyer to fix anything dangerous, but not having an outlet isn't one of those things they consider dangerous.

Most jurisdictions require hard-wired smoke alarms if upgrading the panel, and this is regardless if any walls are removed. However, the authority having jurisdiction may require some new circuits during this upgrade.

Comment: I don't get the impression that any renovations were done, and if that's the case codes are not retroactive.

Comment: My answer is to clear the "fog" as to why they might think their bathroom should have an outlet.